# How to reduce the size of React Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to reduce the size of React Select.

This is my code,

```js
<div>
  <Select
    options={workflowStepAction}
  />
</div>
```

I tried the below code. But it's not working properly,

```js
<div>
  <Select
    maxMenuHeight={190}
    options={workflowStepAction}
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. I think the following is the minimal setting. I could able to reduce the `hight` of the react select.

[image]

This is the code, I used TypeScript for this code.

```js
const targetHeight = 30;

const styles = {
  control: (base: any) => ({
    ...base,
    minHeight: 'initial',
  }),
  valueContainer: (base: any) => ({
    ...base,
    height: `${targetHeight - 1 - 1}px`,
    padding: '0 8px',
  }),
  clearIndicator: (base: any) => ({
    ...base,
    padding: `${(targetHeight - 20 - 1 - 1) / 2}px`,
  }),
  dropdownIndicator: (base: any) => ({
    ...base,
    padding: `${(targetHeight - 20 - 1 - 1) / 2}px`,
  }),
};
```

```html
<Select
  styles={styles}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used styles prop:

```
<Select
    defaultValue={selectedOption}
    onChange={setSelectedOption}
    options={options}
    menuPosition='fixed'
    menuPlacement='auto'
    styles={{
        control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
            ...baseStyles,
            minHeight: '25px',
            fontSize: '15px',
        }),
        dropdownIndicator: (base) => ({
            ...base,
            paddingTop: 0,
            paddingBottom: 0,
        }),
        menuList: (base) => ({
            ...base,
            fontSize: '12px',
        }),
    }}
/>
```

You can find the component's names to select here: https://react-select.com/components

dropdownIndicator default padding is 8px, so to reduce the height, you have to put the top/bottom padding to 0.

I used fontSize on component menuList to reduce the font's size of  the list, and attributes menuPosition and menuPlacement to bring closer the menu near the reduced select.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the size of react-select v5 use this

`sx={{height: 40}}`

Replace 40 with your intended height then use as so;
`<Select sx={{height: 40}} >`